# Hystrix fallbackMethod will not be called in unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, resttemplate, hystrix

I am starting to use Hystrix on my application to deal with data coming from external services. Some main points in my code:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getImagesFallback")
public ImageResultResource getImages(String url) 
{
    ResponseEntity<ResultResource> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(getRequestHeaders()), ResultResource.class);
    return result.getBody().getImageResultResource();
}

public ImageResultResource getImagesFallback(String url, Throwable e) 
{
    return new ImageResultResource();
}
```

In my unit test, I would like to test the fallback case, for example when the external service returns 404 Not Found response, so I mock my test like below:

```
doThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))//
            .when(Mockito.spy(new ImageConnector()))//
            .getImages(myMockedURL)
```

But when I run the test, it seems that the fallbackMethod that I defined above was not called. It returned directly the 404 Not Found that I mocked for the external service while I expect that the fallbackMethod should be catched here and no 404 Not Found will be thrown here.

Can anyone give me hint how can I test my fallbackMethod in this case, or did I make something wrong with the configuration here? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your fallback method needs to have the same signature as the method with the HystrixCommand annotation or the same signature with the addition of a Throwable.  [Here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica#fallback) is the relevant Javanica documentation

```
public ImageResultResource getImagesFallback(String url, Throwable e) {
    return new ImageResultResource();
}
```

Comment: Hi Davin, yes you are right, I did correct the signature for my fallback method but it was still not be called in unit test

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so, your test class have needs @SpringBootTest annotation at the class level?

Comment: yes, I have the annotation @SpringBootTest at the class level of my test also. :(

Comment: Can you post the full test?

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix custom fallback methods throws the exception having the instance of HystrixRuntimeException..
So, you need to catch this exception and use getMessage method of it to print it.